# New programmer here. How do I utilize constructs to create instances of a class (if that's what it's called)? Please see my example

Tags: c#

A friend and I are doing a programming school project, but we're both new programmers and feel as if we're stuck. For the project we have to create a bank system where you have different options, eg. creating an account, transfering money and so on. However, we're not sure how to utilize the constructor to create an instance of the class. This is what we've got so far.

The constructor and a method for creating an account identifier:

```
public class Account
    {
        public int accountID;
        public bool accountStatus;
        public string[] accountInformation;
        private string[] accountSettings;
        private string[] debitCardInformation;
        private string[] transferHistory;
        private double accountBalance;
        private double accountLoan;
        private double accountDebt;
        private double retirementSavings;

        public Account(string firstName, string lastName, double startBalance)
        {
            this.accountID = AccountID();
            this.accountStatus = true;
            this.accountInformation = new string[] {firstName, lastName};
            this.accountSettings = new string[] { };
            this.accountBalance = startBalance;
            this.accountLoan = 0;
            this.accountDebt = 0;
            this.retirementSavings = 0;
        }

        public static int AccountID()
        {
            Random rn = new Random();
            int newAccountID = rn.Next(000000001, 999999999);
            return newAccountID;
        }
    }
```

The program:

```
namespace ConsoleApp14
{
    class Program
    {
        static public List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        static public int nextID = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Intro();
            Actions();
        }

        public static void Intro()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose one of the following options:\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Press '1' to create a new account.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press '2' to log in to an existing one.\n");

            int accessSystem = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            if (accessSystem == 1)
            {
                //LogIn();
            }
            else if (accessSystem == 2)
            {
                //CreateAccount();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Intro();
            }

            Console.Clear();
        }

        public static void Actions()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose one of the following options:\n");
            string[] options = new string[12]
            {
                "Press '1' to switch between accounts.", "Press '2' to check your balance.", "Press '3' to check your debt.",
                "Press '4' to check your loans.", "Press '5' to check your account's status (activated/deactivated).",
                "Press '6' to check your account's information.", "Press '7' to check your debit card information.",
                "Press '8' to check your account's settings.", "Press '9' to withdraw money.", "Press '10' to transfer money.",
                "Press '11' to check your transfer history.", "Press '12' to check your retirement savings."
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(options[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Account test = new Account("Test", "Testerson", 100);
            int responseIndex = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (responseIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    //ChangeAccount();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //CheckAccountBalance();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //CheckAccountDebt();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    //CheckAccountLoans();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    //CheckAccountStatus();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    //CheckAccountInformation();
                    Console.WriteLine("Endnu ikke implementeret");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    //CheckDebitCardInformation();

                    break;
                case 8:
                    //CheckAccountSettings();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    //WithdrawMoney();
                    break;
                case 10:
                    //TransferMoney();
                    break;
                case 11:
                    //CheckTransferHistory();
                    break;
                case 12:
                    //CheckRetirementSavings();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Actions();
                    return;
                    break;
            }
        }

        public static void LogIn()
        {

        }

        public static void CreateAccount()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are already using it on  Account test = new Account("Test", "Testerson", 100);

Comment: You already did it with: `Account test = new Account("Test", "Testerson", 100);`... Could you elaborate on your question?

Comment: ...OT: the positions of calling for Login() and CreateAccount() are mixed up.

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim not even sure if this is the correct way to reply, but our teacher created that instance for us. We're not sure how to create a method for creating the account using the constructor, though.

Comment: @kaffekopp I don't see why that matters? Is it important to change their positions?

Comment: @Anders but you are already calling the constructor, i can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @DamienFlury we're trying to figure out how to create a method for creating an instance of the class using the constructor, if that is the correct way to put it.

Comment: the method is the constructor,the  public Account(string firstName, string lastName, double startBalance) this is the "method"

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim we need to create a method for creating accounts using the constructor, but we're not sure how to do it, especially when you need to be able to create several different accounts.

Comment: @Anders The console text tells the user to "Press '1' to create a new account", but when the user press 1 you call the LogIn() method and vice versa.

Comment: @Anders something like this: `public static Account CreateNewAccount(string firstName, string lastName, double startBalance) => new Account(firstName, lastName, startBalance);`? I don't really know what that should achieve though, since it's just calling forward to the constructor...

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is something like this

```
namespace ConsoltedeTEstes
{
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       //new list of accounts
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

        //add a new account on the list
        accounts.Add(CreateAccount("first name", "last name", 10));

        //Create a single instance using the method
        Account accountTeste = CreateAccount("first name", "last name", 15);
    }

    public static Account CreateAccount(string firstName, string lastName, double startBalance)
    {
        return new Account(firstName, lastName, startBalance);
    }
}


public class Account
{
    public int accountID;
    public bool accountStatus;
    public string[] accountInformation;
    private string[] accountSettings;
    private string[] debitCardInformation;
    private string[] transferHistory;
    private double accountBalance;
    private double accountLoan;
    private double accountDebt;
    private double retirementSavings;

    public Account(string firstName, string lastName, double startBalance)
    {
        this.accountID = AccountID();
        this.accountStatus = true;
        this.accountInformation = new string[] { firstName, lastName };
        this.accountSettings = new string[] { };
        this.accountBalance = startBalance;
        this.accountLoan = 0;
        this.accountDebt = 0;
        this.retirementSavings = 0;
    }

    public static int AccountID()
    {
        Random rn = new Random();
        int newAccountID = rn.Next(000000001, 999999999);
        return newAccountID;
    }
}
```

}

But note that the Method is literally doing the exact same thing of the constructor